# Know if a systemd is really enabled or not

Tags: systemd

I want to figure out if a service is enabled or not.

With the SysV Init was easy. But with `systemctl status <service name>` is confusing and systemd is too complex to dig in.

Specifically, I try enabling with

```
# systemctl enable watchdog.service
```

but after reboot it's gives me this status:

```
# systemctl status watchdog.service
● watchdog.service - watchdog daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

But I can't understand id it's enable but something happening, or if the enable service command failed.

At any moment, starting the service manually works fine:

```
# systemctl start watchdog.service
# systemctl status watchdog.service
● watchdog.service - watchdog daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Qua 2016-12-21 04:03:26 BRST; 2s ago
  Process: 9111 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c [ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options (code=exited, sta
  Process: 9109 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe
 Main PID: 9115 (watchdog)
   CGroup: /system.slice/watchdog.service
           └─9115 /usr/sbin/watchdog

watchdog[9115]: int=1s realtime=yes sync=no soft=no mla=24 mem=0
watchdog[9115]: ping: no machine to check
watchdog[9115]: file: no file to check
watchdog[9115]: pidfile: no server process to check
systemd[1]: Started watchdog daemon.
watchdog[9115]: interface: no interface to check
watchdog[9115]: temperature: no sensors to check
watchdog[9115]: test=none(0) repair=none(0) alive=/dev/watchdog heartbeat=none to=root no_act=
watchdog[9115]: watchdog now set to 15 seconds
watchdog[9115]: hardware watchdog identity: Broadcom BCM2835 Watchdog timer
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`systemctl status` tell us the unit is in status `static`:

> ```
> # systemctl status watchdog.service
> ● watchdog.service - watchdog daemon
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: inactive (dead)
> ```

From `man systemctl`:

> "`static`" | The unit file is not enabled, and has no provisions for enabling in the "`[Install]`" unit file section.

This basically means there is no `[Install]` section in the service file and thus you cannot enable it by `systemctl enable`. The way to enable such unit is to pull it into a dependency chain, i.e. make it being required or wanted by other units.